Azure Web App, Python, and MS SQL. pyodbc error [08S01] Error code 0x68 (104) (SQLExecDirectW)
I have a basic website, that execute multiple selects from a MSSQL. No one uses the website (just a website for me to test my knowledge). My challenge is that after a while, I have this error:

pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08S01', '[08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18
for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x68 (104) (SQLExecDirectW)')

I already did a internet search.
Came across a few suggestions, including this one: Handle TCP Provider: Error code 0x68 (104)
On this article, it's an intermittent error. Mine looks like a closed connection after a period of time. If I restart the Azure Web App and keep doing refresh during the day, I don't face the issue. It's only after a few hours of inactivity.
I tried a reconnect without success. This is my code
odbc_str = f'DRIVER={driver};SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};UID={username};PWD={password};Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;autocommit=True'
connection = pyodbc.connect(odbc_str, readonly=True)
cursor_conn = connection.cursor()

def get_results(seasonID):
    global connection, cursor_conn, odbc_str # Usage of global variables is not best practice
    if not connection:  # Because the website does not have lots of traffic, I suspect the connection is drop
        connection = pyodbc.connect(odbc_str, readonly=True)
        cursor_conn = connection.cursor()
    resultsQuery = "SELECT * FROM season_view"
    return cursor_conn.execute(resultsQuery).fetchall()

Any suggestion?

This question is similar to: Handle TCP Provider: Error code 0x68 (104). If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You shouldn't cache a connection forever, use pools or at least check if connecton is still alive and recreate it. Also, what happens if multiple users call get_results

Multiple users, means two devices accessing the site simultaneously don't create an issue. I was thinking that "if not connection" was an attempt to see if it was still alive, Bad coding?
Looks like I need to try to figure out how to use pools

What do you mean with "don't create an issue"

Sorry. Means more than user accessing the website, don't create errors

Please write meaningful titles, as noted in [ask]; your title is just tags and tells us nothing about the problem you are asking about.

Good shout Thom A. Edited the title. Might be useful to say that I'm not a developer.

It will if they both access the db at exactly the same time, connection object usually can't be used from multiple threads, although maybe python would prevent that, i've no idea.

Changed my code to open close a connection every time a query is made.
Double checked and the errors were gone.
def get_results(seasonID):
    global odbc_str
    connection = pyodbc.connect(odbc_str, readonly=True)
    cursor_conn = connection.cursor()
    resultsQuery = "SELECT * FROM season_view"
    execute_qry = cursor_conn.execute(resultsQuery).fetchall()
    cursor_conn.close()
    connection.close()
    return execute_qry

